# In Sublime Python console, how can I locate a class and method that a console run command runs?

Tags: python, sublimetext2

From the console

```
>>> sublime.run_command('test_application_args',{'arg1':'5', 'arg2':'4'})
running TestApplicationArgsCommand
arg1: 5
arg2: 4
```

I want to find what .py file has that command, and if it isn't one if it's some old py file I removed and somehow the pyc file got left behind, then I want to delete the culprit pyc file.  How can I find out where this class is located?

I have a similar class and method in one file.

(this one I think was called TestApplicationArgsCommand but I renamed it to test if it was being called, and I changed what it printed, but it didn't change what was outputted from that run command in the console, so I know this one isn't it.

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class TestApplicationArgsPodCommand(sublime_plugin.ApplicationCommand):
    def run(self, arg1, arg2):
        print("running TestApplicationArgsPodCommand")
        print("arg1___: " + arg1)
        print("arg2: " + arg2)
```

And I have similar ones in another file  but I see from what they print (besides the fact that the others don't take 2 args), that they aren't the ones being called either.

How can I find out where this class and method is that is getting called?

Can the python console tell me?

Comment: Not really an answer, but using "Find in files" (`ctrl+shift+f`) may help you find it.

Comment: @DanielB good idea I still don't see it listed from that

Comment: @barlop when you did the find in file, what folders were in your project? If you weren't already, I'd open the `Packages` folder completely. That way you know all possibilities have been searched. If you still can't find it, you could also try writing a small script to remove the `*.pyc` files. Thess will be generated (assuming a `.py` file exists). To be safe, you could always copy the packages folder out as a backup, run the remove script, then start ST again. If something is broken, you can revert it.

Comment: @skuroda I used powergrep(program for scanning txt files and maybe docs, not free though maybe free alternatives), and looked through all .py files, didn't find anything, then I looked into any programs that'd decompile pyc files, to py files then scan them, I found some options but didn't get round to doing them. Then I deleted the pycs, they're only in the users subdirectory 'cos I put all mine there. And it's ok but I don't know what the culprit pyc file was.